# Gems that require other gems (Gem dependecy issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When developing some task manage app using rails,

I encountered the error saying 
" 
remote: ! Failed to install gems via Bundler. 
remote: ! Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku
"

I fixed the situation by deleting the gem requiring sqlite3 and there's no problem now.
However, I wonder what if the gem requiring sqlite3 was necessary for the app and impossible to be deleted.

Is there anyway to handle such situation?

I expect the way of not deleting associated gems which are necessary for the app. thx.

Comment: I would remove sqlite3 gem as that's the one not required by heroku. In anycase, if bundle install is complete, you have nothing to worry, if later any gem is required, the application will ask and you just need to add it and bundle install again

Comment: you can refer this [heroku dev center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Removing only sqlite3 itself was impossible. That's why I deleted the gem which required sqlite3 and did bundle installation again. Though I wonder it may be the case I just didn't know the way.

Comment: And it seems that what I did was exactly the same with the one on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3. I just wondered there's any other way but to delete the gem which requires sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule of thumb is that a gem should not list any unnecessary runtime dependencies. If a dependency is listed there're two cases:

1. The gem really needs it: then whole gem cannot be used along with it because of issues with dependency gem and there's nothing you can do other that use something else
2. Dependency is unnecessary or optional: then gem should be fixed not to include it as a hard dependency. Since most gems are opensource - you can open an issue or fix it yourself and submit a pull-request.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The gem was the one introduced in the book and it's famous. So I think it's the case 1. And thank you for letting me know that there's some case that the gem itself should be fixed. It'll be my knowledge.